# Titanium App Apple store rejection due to non-public API focus:

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have an appcelerator titanium app that I have summited several versions of to the Apple store for beta testing and have had approved. The most recent version was rejected with the message:

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> focus:

Asking for clarification they replied:

> Thank you for your reply. Our team has re-reviewed this app to ensure our findings were accurate, we found this app contains references to the following selectors:
>
> "focus:" was found in the method -[TiRootViewController manuallyRotateToOrientation:duration:]

I am not trying to use any non-public APIs and nothing related to this has changed since the last app submission that was approved.
Is this a titanium problem? Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Does your Ti app code contains any orientation handling code?

Comment: Nothing specific in my code.

Comment: Try to search for the strings provided by Apple **"focus:" was found in the method -[TiRootViewController manuallyRotateToOrientation:duration:]** in the generated Xcode project to know where the issue is. You really need to know the location of file which is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I commented out the "focus:" line and the app was approved.

Comment: Which Titanium SDK are you using? Maybe this is something new. This could be a big problem, you may be interested also on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573151/app-rejection-issue-2-5-1-apps-that-use-non-public-apis-will-be-rejected-since

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search for the strings provided by Apple:

**"focus:"** was found in the method -**[TiRootViewController manuallyRotateToOrientation:duration:]** in the generated Xcode project to know where the issue is.

You need to know the location of file which is causing this issue and comment out any of those strings informed by Apple.